# Javascript/PHP auto submit keeps submitting form

Tags: javascript, php

This code:

```
<?php
    if(isset($_GET['submit']))
    {
    ?>
    <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        document.getElementById('up').submit(); // SUBMIT FORM
    </script>
    </head>
<?php
    }
?>
```

form:

```
<form name="up" id="up" action="" method="post">
<textarea name="text" rows="40" cols="100"></textarea>
<input type="submit" name="ingameban" value="Save in-game banlist (Upload to server and make new bans take effect)" style="height: 64px; width: 550px;" />
</form>
```

Keeps looping all the time, the same result as smashing the reload button.
It has to submit the form when the url states ?submit=submit

What to do to fix this?

Thanks

Comment: Well, duh! That's what happens when the page keeps reloading and you keep submitting, you get a loop

Comment: How about including the form, and showing us how you get an element by ID in the head, without any sort of DOM ready handler ?

Comment: You might have mean  `if(!isset($_GET['submit']))` - however that might not be set unless you do `document.getElementById('submitButtonId').click()` instead. Your code will submit for as long the URL has `?submit=something` in it unless the target of the `up` form is elsewhere.

Comment: Added the form to the question

Comment: That does not make sense then. You do NOT have a field called submit but called ingameban. How do manage to set a field called `submit`? Also is your script before or after the form?

Comment: @mplungjan probably by typing it in the address bar of his browser (I think).

Comment: That is my guess too or link to it

Comment: G72: If you have something like `<a href="mypage.html?submit=true">Banlist</a>` to reload your page with submit=true, then you will get a loop unless you remove the submit=true from the URL

Answer (score 1):

Your approach is right, but the problem is that `submit=submit` in the URL is copied to the new URL used to submit the form. Because in your form you have:

```
<form name="up" id="up" action="" method="post">
```

Since action is empty, the exact same URL is used, so `submit=submit` stays in the URL. Instead, provide the proper URL in action. Then `submit=submit` won't be copied to the new URL:

```
<form name="up" id="up" action="/my-url" method="post">
```

Answer (score 0):

How about setting an input hidden field, which you mark as true when you submit.

Check this field before submitting again.

Try this:

```
<?php
    if(isset($_GET['submit']))
    {
        if(isset($_GET['submitted']) && $_GET['submitted'] == 'false') {
    ?>
    <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        document.getElementById('submitted').value = 'true';
        document.getElementById('up').submit(); // SUBMIT FORM
    </script>
    </head>
        }
<?php
    }
?>
<body>
<form method="get" id="up">
<input type="hidden" id="submitted" name="submitted" value="false" />
...
</form>
```

Comment: That would run before the field existed

Comment: Did you even try this? You have a closing curly bracket of the second-level if branch **outside PHP tags**. It's also overcomplicating things, + you changed OP's form into GET with no reason.